# Find the sum of DATETIME differences within a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
---------------------------------
| id | class_id | time | status |
---------------------------------
| 1  | 1        | <>   | 1      |
---------------------------------
| 2  | 2        | <>   | 1      |
---------------------------------
| 3  | 1        | <>   | 0      |
---------------------------------
| 4  | 2        | <>   | 0      |
---------------------------------
```

I want a query that will see that the first row has `class_id = 1` and `status = 1`. It will then look for the next row with `class_id = 1` and `status = 0`, and find the `time` difference between the two (`time` is `DATETIME`).

At the end of all this, it will return me a sum of all time differences (i.e. `(row 1 - row 3) + (row2 - row4)`).

How is this possible? In generalisation, the question is about getting an aggregate total of differences between rows in a table, based off a condition.

Comment: Would each `class_id` have no more and no less than 2 recorsd: one with `status = 0` and one with `status = 1`?

Comment: @marlan No - it will be something like `status = 0`, `status = 1`, `status = 0`, `status = 1` - not necessarily consecutively within the table, but within that order, yes.

Comment: First - according to what?

Comment: @jarlh I'm sorry? It will find the differences between consecutive `status = 1` and `status = 0` rows, based on their `class_id`, and then find the sum of all those differences.

Comment: @think123: jarlh's question was reasonable; for you it may be obvious that the order of IDs in your table represents the order of its records, but such is not necessarily the case.

Comment: For each `class_id`, does it always have 2 or 4 or 6 or etc records which means `status = 1` and `status = 0` always appear in pair?

Comment: @Reno: Haha, I dismissed this thought for being so unlikely, but it would make the task so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every status 0 record we search the latest status 1 record. This is from all previous status 1 records take the latest.

```
select 
  class_id,
  sum
  (
    timestampdiff
    (
      second,
      (
        select s1.time 
        from mytable s1 
        where s1.status = 1 
        and s1.class_id = s0.class_id
        and s1.id < s0.id
        order by s1.id desc limit 1
      ),
      s0.time
    )
  ) as diffsecs
from mytable s0
where status = 0
group by class_id;
```